# what does 'AVC avc: denied { name_connect }' mean, and how do i prevent it?

Tags: amazon-ec2

i had an Amazon Linux 2023 web server that had been running normally for weeks now. this morning, it became inexplicably unresponsive for about two hours before (inexplicably!) recovering. according to our logs, none of the user-facing server applications crashed, the web server was simply unable to query the `mongod` database daemon running on the same node during this time.

when inspecting the `journalctl` logs, i noticed an anomaly logged within a few seconds of the time the server began behaving abnormally.

```
Feb 02 18:06:51 ceres.swiftinit.org audit[374371]: 
AVC avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=374371 comm="NIO-ELT-0-#1" dest=27017 
scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
tcontext=system_u:object_r:mongod_port_t:s0 
tclass=tcp_socket permissive=1
```

**`374371`** is the PID of the web server and **`27017`** is the standard `mongod` port. what does this log event mean? is it related to the application being unable to communicate with `mongod` during this time?

Answer (score 0):

That message is a denial from SELinux, indicating that the process (374371) tried to do something that it's not configured to do - in this case connect to the network via (I think) a DNS name.

You /can/ allow it by running `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`, but if it was working fine normally and then briefly wasn't then I'd be tempted to leave the setting off. It may be that for some brief reason the mongo service was resolved via a non-local IP, and HTTPD tried to use that?

Either way - SELinux is the reason for the message, and it's worth doing some investigating and reading about it before blindly turning it off. It's designed to prevent malware from escaping the confines of an application, so may just be doing it's job.